# Get a list of domains from list via regex

Tags: php, regex

i have list of domains and another information

```
domain1.com;somedata1;somedata2;2012-03-02;somedata3;somedata4;somedata5
domain2.com;somedata5;somedata8;2013-06-18;somedata4;somedata2;somedata1
domain3.org;somedata9;somedata2;2012-03-02;somedata3;somedata4;somedata5
domain4.com;somedata1;somedata2;2015-04-18;somedata3;somedata4;somedata5
domain5.com;somedata1;somedata2;2012-03-02;somedata3;somedata4;somedata5
domain6.biz;somedata5;somedata8;2013-06-18;somedata4;somedata2;somedata1
domain7.org;somedata9;somedata2;2012-03-02;somedata3;somedata4;somedata5
domain8.com;somedata1;somedata2;2015-04-18;somedata3;somedata4;somedata5
```

i need get list of .com domains where date is 2012-03-02

i need to use something like:

```
preg_match('(.*?.com)   ????  /i', $data, $matches);
```

Comment: So what have you tried to do?

Comment: Using a regex for this is very wrong. Use a CSV parser and iterate over the rows and then check the value of the data column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all('~^\S+?.com(?=;[^;]*+;[^;]*+;2012-03-02;)~mi', $data, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  preg_match_all( '/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.com*)+):?(\d+)?\/?(.+?)(2012\-03\-02)/i', $data, $matches );
  print_r( $matches[1] );
```